# Infinispan equivalent of IMap.values(Predicate)

Tags: java, infinispan

Is there an equivalent of Hazelcast's `IMap.values(Predicate)` for Infinispan ? And possibly non-blocking (async) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you trying to do. Infinispan extends Java's Stream functionality so you can use the Stream interface to get the filtered values.

Examples

```java
//filter by key
cache.values().stream()
    .filterKeys(/*set with keys*/)
    .forEach(/*do something with the value*/) //or collect()

//filter by key and value
cache.getAdvancedCache().cacheEntrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> /*check key and value using entry.getKey() or entry.getValue()*/)
    .map(StreamMarshalling.entryToValueFunction()) //extract the value only
    .forEach(/*do something with the value*/; //or collect()
```

Infinispan documentation about streams [here](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/developing/developing.html#streams).

Comment: do you plan to have a non-blocking version ?

Comment: @rico We do, but there is not a public API for it yet :)

Comment: @Mudokonman When do you plan to release it as public ?

Comment: @rico It should come with https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-9893, but I don't know when this will be completed.